# Hpack or pre-processor platform info

Tags: haskell, yaml, ghc, haskell-stack, hpack

I am using hpack+stack for a project and there is a hardcoded path (used for debugging, I don't want to do this properly) which are differs for mac os x and linux. Right now I have it on a gitignored file on it's own and that file differs between my workstations but I would much rather have the pre-processor deal with it.

Ideally I would like something equivalent to`#ifdef __linux__`, which dosnt work. I would even be happy with manipulating `package.yaml` to come up with `-D` compiler flags. Does hpack (which I think uses `Data.Yaml`) have this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hpack` does support this: [hpack conditionals](https://github.com/sol/hpack#conditionals). It looks something like this:

```
when:
  - condition: os(darwin)
  then:
    extra-lib-dirs: lib/darwin
  else:
    extra-lib-dirs: lib/linux
```